# ER Schema "Optimisation"

Tags: schema

I am trying to make an ER Schema for a person. The person will have Current Address and Permanent Address. So far I have it so that both Current and Permanent Address are Composite Attributes and they have the same Attributes.

[image]

If you look at the picture you see that it is pretty much a copy of the same attributes. How can I combine them/make this better?

Answer (score 2):

I'm with @sa555. but to exemplify better, you can adda `Person_Has_Address` entity, that has a relation to a new `AddressType` table.

It would be like:

[image]

`AddressType` would have two records: "CurrentAddress" and "PermanetAddress". In the case more address type wouldd come up (like mailing address, or work address), your are covered-up

Answer (score 1):

Currently you model both addresses as separate, composite attributes. Instead you could model them as separate entities and connect it to the `Person` entity using different relations like shown below:

[image: ER diagram]

That way, you may have less redundant information. If, for example, for one person the current and permanent address are identical you just have to point towards the same address entity, instead of duplicating all attributes like in your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have an "address type" attribute. Then you only need one address entity whether it's a permanent or current address

Comment: "Entity" as in the rectangle in the diagram?

Comment: Can you explain it more? I don't understand.